# Rebuilding TFS 2010 SCRUM template reports?

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports

Is there a way to rebuild the reports that are configured when you intstall the `TFS 2010 SCRUM` template? We had changed the domain name of the server and when we run the reports the old server name is coming up in the URL inside TFS 2010

Update: I think the URL is coming from the report server. Not sure where it is being stored though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come to find out it was an issue with the TFS setup and the connection to TFS through Team Explorer.

First, make sure you reset ALL the paths that you can form the old domain name to the new name in TFS Admin console on the server. You don’t have a lot of control over the Reporting Service URLS, but that ends up not mattering. Just make sure all the paths for you SharePoint sites and TFS web location are setup with the new name.

Second, in Team Explorer inside VS2010, make sure you connect to you team project using the new URL. Next right click on the team project in the Team Explorer and select the Team Project Settings -> Portal Settings. A window should pop up with the URLS to your resources. They should reflect your new domain name since you connected with it, but if not make sure you change the domain name. The OK button is grayed out. I assume this is because I am not making any changes. What I did to enable it was I unchecked the “Reports and dashboards…” check box. I then rechecked it and the OK button should enable. Click OK and your project will update.

After that, my URLs were correct and everything was as it should have been.